# WPF/Multithreading: UI Dispatcher in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

So say in an MVVM environment, I'm in a background thread and I'd like to run an update on a ui control. So normally I'd go myButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(blabla) but I don't have access to myButton (because the viewmodel doesn't have access to the view's controls). So what is the normal pattern for doing this?

(I guess there's always binding, but I'd like to know how to do it via the dispatcher)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486758/is-wpf-dispatcher-the-solution-of-multi-threading-problems ?

Comment: Not a duplicate...he's asking how to get a dispatcher from a background thread launched by a ViewModel (which normally doesn't have access to a dispatcher).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I usually use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`: since `Application.Current` is static, you don't need a reference to a control

Comment: And how will you unit test your view models without an application object?

Comment: @Geert van Horrik You could mock the application object for unit testing your view models.  Sorry for the necro comment - I just stumbled on this SO article while searching for a valid MVVM solution for multithreaded programming.

Comment: @aaronburro nothing prevents you from putting it behind an abstraction that you can mock in unit tests.

Comment: I think you've even got a nice blog post about doing exactly that

Answer (score 15):

From [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) source code :

```
public static class Execute
{
    private static Action<System.Action> executor = action => action();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the framework using the current dispatcher.
    /// </summary>
    public static void InitializeWithDispatcher()
    {
#if SILVERLIGHT
        var dispatcher = Deployment.Current.Dispatcher;
#else
        var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
#endif
        executor = action =>{
            if(dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                action();
            else dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the action on the UI thread.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The action to execute.</param>
    public static void OnUIThread(this System.Action action)
    {
        executor(action);
    }
}
```

Before using it you'll have to call `Execute.InitializeWithDispatcher()` from the UI thread then you can use it like this `Execute.OnUIThread(()=>SomeMethod())`

Comment: I still get the error if I use Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher. It works correctly if I use Application.Current.Dispatcher.

Answer (score 5):

I tend to have my ViewModels inherit from DependencyObject and ensure that they are constructed on the UI thread, which poises them perfectly to handle this situation - they have a `Dispatcher` property that corresponds to the UI thread's dispatcher.  Then, you don't need to pollute your view with the ViewModel's implementation details.

Some other pluses:

- Unit testability: you can unit test these without a running application (rather than relying on `Application.Current.Dispatcher`)
- Loose coupling between View & ViewModel
- You can define dependency properties on your ViewModel and write no code to update the view as those properties change.

Comment: DependencyObject is quite heavy, what you really need is DispatcherObject. It has a simple implementation: its constructor calls Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher and stores the value in a field for later use. If you cannot add a base class to your ViewModel, you can easily implement what DispatcherObject is doing.

Answer (score 4):

The ViewModelBase of [Catel](http://catel.codeplex.com) has a Dispatcher property that you can use.

Comment: GetCurrentDispatcher method in DispatcherHelper class. https://catel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Catel.MVVM/Catel.MVVM.NET40/Windows/Threading/Helpers/Dispatcherhelper.cs

Answer (score 0):

You could raise an event on your View Model (perhaps using a naming convention to indicate it's going to be raised from a non-UI thread - e.g. NotifyProgressChangedAsync). Then your View whom is attached to the event can deal with the dispatcher appropriately.

Or, you could pass a delegate to a synchronizing function to your View Model (from your View).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the UI thread's dispatcher to the ViewModel's constructor and store it in the VM.

Take note that each thread may have its own dispatcher. You are going to need the UI thread's!

Comment: The fact that there may be multiple Dispatchers you have to worry about (while a bad design idea, but it happens) suggests that passing in a Dispatcher is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you don't need the Dispatcher in a ViewModel (> 99% of the time). Earlier versions of .NET didn't marshal PropertyChanged events to the UI thread appropriately, which caused issues. There was a way around it, which required you to raise that event in a way that was aware of the Dispatcher and could automatically marshal when needed. .NET 3.5 and above do this automatically now.

Because the Dispatcher is a UI concept, its presence in a ViewModel is a huge code smell. It suggests that you are doing something wrong. More likely, you either need to inject something which abstracts your ViewModel from the UI resource you are manipulating (changing the mouse cursor is a good example), or you've actually coupled the View to the ViewModel. In the latter case, you can usually fix this with some kind of attached behaviour which will subscribe to events and property changes on your ViewModel.

There is a hangup with this... CollectionChanged does have thread affinity (indirectly through CollectionViews which get automatically created by WPF), and the best way around this is to check for SynchronizationContexts on the event delegate subsribers when raising that event. It stinks, but it still doesn't require you to pass the Dispatcher to the VM.